# Using the offer object and categories on a schema.org model

Tags: schema.org

I'm currently working on using schema.org for the events database on my site. We don't sell anything, we just try to be able to show all kinds of events (concert,  activities for children, art exhibition, etc) some of them are free, some of them are not, and for some we don't even know, and we don't often have precise information on the price(s).

So, my markup is correct according to google's testing tool, but it says I should have an offer object, and I can't seem to know how to put it. In my database, regarding prices I have these fields :

- 'free', an enumeration ['yes','no','not communicated']
- 'tariff', an optional free text field, with a price or price range, and general information about prices, like how it's cheaper for young or old people.

From what I saw, when it's free, I can simply put an offer with a price at 0, when it's not I don't have a price, or may be I have it, but something written in my own langage (not a well sorted list of numeric prices), I'm not even talking about when we don't even know if it's free or not.

**so my first question is : is it possible to make a schema.org offer with so little information ?**

my second problem is about categories, I have categories for my events, like for example, there's an art exhibit showing photographies, so its two categories are 'art exhibit' and 'photography' ('art exhibit' being the main one).

**my second question is : how can I use those values to define my events better ?** I suppose I must make my categories coincide with schema.org subevents, like musicEvents, or whatever, but I lose a little accuracy there, so I was wondering if there was another way, and I think it's not practical to change the type depending on the categories it fits in.

well, thanks in advance for reading this.

Comment: Your second problem should be a separate question, as it doesn’t seem to be closely related to the first problem. So please [edit] your second problem out, and create another question post for it.

Answer (score 0):

Schema.org does not require any properties, so an [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer) without a [`price`](http://schema.org/price) is totally fine.

Consumers of the content, on the other hand, might require certain properties/types for whatever they do.

For example, Google lists [what is required for showing their Events Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/events). There you can see that having an `Offer` for an `Event` (via the `offers` property) is optional, but if you specify it, `price` and `priceCurrency` are required for the `Offer`.

In general, it’s best to specify as much data as possible, so if it’s an offer but you don’t know the price, use `Offer` and add all other properties you can provide content for.
However, it *might* be the case (I don’t know it; if so, it would certainly be a pity!) that Google  Search doesn’t show anything at all if you have an `Offer` without `price` for an `Event`, instead of "falling back" to the Event Rich Snippet that doesn’t have an `Offer` in the first place.